# Passing tables as parameters in Nim

Tags: dictionary, parameters, nim-lang

hopefully an easy question.. I've been playing around with Nim and have realised I need to pass a table (dictionary, map, in some other languages), but I can't seem to figure out the syntax for declaring it in `doStuff()`

```
import tables

proc doStuff(n:int, t:[int, int]) =   # How should I declare 't' here?
    if n == 0:
        return
    t[n] = (n * 10) 
    echo "length of t = " & ($len(t))
    doStuff(n+1, t)
    
proc main() =
    var tbl = initTable[int, int]()
    echo "length of tbl = " & ($len(tbl))
    tbl[0] = 0
    doStuff(5, tbl)
    echo "length of tbl = " & ($len(tbl))
    
main()
```

The above gets me `Error: type expected, but got: [int, int]`

Sorry if this is basic, but my Googling hasn't given me an answer yet

Many TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it, it should be like below:

```
import tables

proc doStuff(n: int, t: var Table[int, int]) =
    if n == 0:
        return
    t[n] = n * 10
    echo "length of t = " & $len(t)
    doStuff(n + 1, t)
    
proc main() =
    var tbl = initTable[int, int]()
    echo "length of tbl = " & $len(tbl)
    tbl[0] = 0
    doStuff(5, tbl)
    echo "length of tbl = " & $len(tbl)
    
main()
```

You have to use `var Table[int, int]` instead of `Table[int, int]` because you are mutating the `tbl` variable recursively, so you need to pass by reference instead of by value.